# Is the runtime instance ignored on a call to a static function through an instance?

Tags: java, null, static-methods, classcastexception

Java has the unfortunate allowed syntax of calling static methods on an instance, although this comes with a warning.

From the following example it seems that the compiler ignores the instance, and calls the static method directly according to the compile time class as evidenced by it succeeding though a null reference.

However from the following example, it seems that the compiler still does type checking on the instance,

```
class Example 
{
    static void f1() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example1 = null;
        example1.f1();                 // works OK
        ((Example) null).f1();         // works OK
        ((Example) (Object) ("")).f1();  // throws cast exception
    }
}
```

Is this true? Why can't the compiler ignore the run time instance on what is on the left side of a static call?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with calling a static method, but rather with trying to cast (Object)("") (which is a String) to an instance of Example, which it is clearly not

Answer (score 2):

The `ClassCastException` is thrown before the method is even called.

You do

```
String str = "";
Object o = (Object) str;
Example e = (Example) o;  // exception
e.f1(); // never reached
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler needs to know which f1() method is called. So it needs to cast left side.

```
class Example 
  {
    static void f1() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example1 = null;
        ((Example2) (Example) (Object) ("")).f1(); 
  }
}

class Example2{
   public void f1(){}
}
```

Comment: It's a static method. Shouldn't the compile time type be enough?